# sed to insert characters in a specific column

Tags: sed, awk

Can anyone tell me how to insert `chr` to every character in the first column.

**file in**

```
1 34566 34765    
2 45678 45789
3 34567 34799
X 67895 66900
Y 34567 34890
```

**file out**

```
chr1 34566 34765
chr2 45678 45789
chr3 34567 34799
chrX 67895 66900
chrY 34567 34890
```

I can't figure out how to make `sed -i` apply to a specific column. I'm not good with the syntax so if you could break down your explanation I would be grateful. Also, would it be better to use awk for this?

Comment: If the title brought you here because you want to replace at some specific column that is not the first, use a regex that makes a group starting at the beginning of the line and matching a specific number of any-character, like this: `echo internal | sed '1s/^\(.\{5\}\)/\1natio/'` which turns internal into international on the first line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/^/chr/' file.in > file.out
```

You don't need the `-i`-flag because you aren't overwriting the input-file **file.in**.

With awk:

```
awk '{print "chr"$0}' file.in > file.out
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's|^|chr|' file_in > file_out
```

This does a substitution (`s`) at the beginning of each line (`^`) and replacing it with the characters "chr". The pipes (`|`) are just separators.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '{print "chr"$0}' file
```

To store the changes back to the file:

```
awk '{print "chr"$0}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Why do you use the `&&` and not `;` and why do you use the tmp-file at all?

Comment: Using `&&` ensures that the file is only overwritten if the previous command succeeds. You cannot do `command file > file`, this is called `clobbing`, the shell will empty the file first meaning you will be left with a empty file.

Comment: I understand the clobbing part. But the only difference from `command file > tmp ; mv tmp file` to `command file > tmp && mv tmp file` is the error message I am getting from the former when awk can't succeed?

Answer (score 1):

`$ cat file.in
  1 34566 34765
2 45678 45789
  3 34567 34799
X 67895 66900
Y 34567 34890`

`$ awk '$1="chr"$1 {print}' file.in
chr1 34566 34765
chr2 45678 45789
chr3 34567 34799
chrX 67895 66900
chrY 34567 34890`

In essence, you are redirecting value of "chr"$1 back to $1 regardless if there are spaces before column 1 or not and still print out the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\s*/chr/'
```

just to be sur that no white space are before you object. If you are sur of, no need of th \s

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print "chr"$0}'
```

Works for the file in question because there are no field separators.  For that case you can use (for a pipe delimited file for instance):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|";OFS="|"} {$97="chr"$0;print}'
```